# Why doesn't the national ignition facility use one big slab of laser glass?

Tags: laser

The amplifier section has lots of massive slabs of nd:glass but I noticed an individual beam line has more than one slab. I read that the angle they are at is brewsters angle and that minimizes reflective loss, and I can't think why there should be gaps between each slab cause then there'd be more reflections right?

Comment: One giant slab is (1) harder to make, and (2) harder to replace when necessary.

Comment: and (3) harder to pump

Comment: Jon, when you say harder to pump, I assume you mean with the same input power you'd get less lasing? But why would that be? As far as reflections go I would think the light from the flash lamps would go in through the sides of a single slab with less reflection loss easier than a bunch of broken up slabs. Part of the reason I'm contemplating this is because I assumed there would be better lasing due to more atoms in the medium catching more pumped light, and more chances for the beam to adsorb that light.